# Mac Cocoa WebView (WebKit) - YouTube videos show as black squares but audio still works and able to right click

Tags: macos, webview, youtube, webkit

I am trying to access youtube.com through a WebKit WebView in my native Mac App.

The problem is that YouTube videos just show as black squares (see image below).  However, if I click them they start to play (but stay black) - the sounds starts.  I can also right click and the YouTube right click menu comes up (with things like 'Stats for Nerds').

Does anyone know what is happening here?

I use the standard WebView component, dragged in in Interface Builder.  In my header I have the standard:

```
IBOutlet WebView *firstWebView;
```

and in my .m the standard:

```
[firstWebView setHidden:FALSE];
[[firstWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtube.com"]]];
```

The same thing happens when I access a site with an embedded YouTube video.

Thanks!

Sam

[image: Black square where player should be]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - as of OS X Mavericks you'll need to call this for WebView's if you want Flash to render correctly:

```
[self.webView setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters:YES];
```

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-CH2-SW49